# How to highlight unsorted elements in a majorly sorted list in excel

Tags: excel, sorting

Considering the following example list:

```
1
2
3
10
11
4
9
8
5
6
```

what rule would highlight the unsorted elements, so that the following list is achieved:

```
1
2
3
**10**
**11**
4
**9**
**8**
5
6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a rule based on a formula similar to the following:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:$A$10,"<"&A1)>0
```

[image]

Comment: What if I had blanks in the column and the range was from 5001 to 5814?

Comment: Same logic would apply. COUNTIF can handle blanks.